# After emptying select option with jQuery .empty() can you restore them?

Tags: jquery

I'm emptying my options like this based on the value of another select:

```
$('option', '#reasonCode').empty().val('');
```

Problem I'm having, is restoring the options if the user changes his answer back.  Is there an easy solution to this, or do I have to rebuild my options using ajax?

And to be clear, I'm trying to restore a list of about 20 options.

Here is a fiddle that shows the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/hX2MY/6/

As you can see, it is almost working, but the options are all on one line.

Comment: `empty()` removes the inner HTML, so no, you can't restore them.

Comment: you can backup them in your js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save them in a variable before you delete them.

```
var allLI = $('option', '#reasonCode').html()
```

or

```
var allLI = $('option', '#reasonCode').contents().clone()
```

And then

```
// delete
$('option', '#reasonCode').empty().val('');

//restores
$('option', '#reasonCode').html(allLI);
```

---

Another method as mentioned in the comments below.

```
var opt = $('select', '#reasonCode').clone(); // save the option
$('select', '#reasonCode').remove(); //remove it
$('#reasonCode').append(opt); // append it back
```

Comment: never use `.html()` to serialise and then de-serialise DOM elements if you can avoid it - it destroys event handlers and other meta-data attached to those elements.

Comment: @Alnitak I see, does `append()` do that too?

Comment: no, `.append()` will happily preserve any meta data on those elements.  I would _probably_ `.clone()` the entire select rather than the individual `option` elements to get the text nodes instead of using `.contents()`

Comment: This solution almost works... but for each option it is placing ALL of the options on one line... making a huge mess. Do you just iterate through them, or is there an easier solution?

Comment: @Patrick not sure I understand what you mean. [I made this fiddle but it seems to work fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/hX2MY/). how exactly did you use it?

Comment: I'm not trying to remove the entire select box; in fact that stays.  I'm just trying to set the val to null, if one option is selected, and if the others are selected the options are presented again.  I'm setting to null to be sure that an incompatible answer is not saved based on the select of another.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Patrick [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/hX2MY/1/). also another option would be to set `disabled` on the `select`

Comment: @Patrick this was not in your original question. can you please update your post explaining more or maybe make a fiddle, I am having problems understanding without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31355/discussion-between-spokey-and-patrick)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using .detach() instead. This removes elements from the DOM but you can save them to a variable and reattach them later if you want.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/